# My edit button adds a new item and my new item link does not work. This is REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues with React using JSON server, my edit buttons adds a new item when it's supposed to edit the current item and the new item link does not work, it should open a form (the same the edit button opens) and when I hit save it should save to the array the new item. Any ideas please?

I have omitted all the imports to save space. This is App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
          <Route index element={<h1>Welcome</h1>} />
          <Route path="products" element={<ProductsList />}>
            <Route index element={<p>Select a Product for more details</p>}/>
            <Route path="new" element={<ProductForm />} />
            <Route path=":productId/edit" element={<ProductForm />} />
            <Route path=":productId" element={<Product />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<h1>Product Not Found</h1>} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>Page Not Found</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is Home.js

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/products" className="nav-link">Products</Link>
            <Link to="/newProduct" className="nav-link">New Product</Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <Stack gap={3} className="col-md-10 mx-auto mt-3">
        <Outlet />
      </Stack>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This is ProductForm.js

```
function ProductForm() {
  let [product, setProduct] = useState({
    id: "",
    productName: "",
    description: "",
    price: "",
  });

  let { getProduct, addProduct, updateProduct } = useContext(ProductContext);
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  let { id, productName, description, price } = product;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id === undefined) return;
    async function fetch() {
      await getProduct(id).then((product) => setProduct(product));
    }
    fetch();
  }, [id]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setProduct((preValue) => {
      return { ...preValue, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    });
  }

  function addOrUpdate() {
    if (id === undefined) {
      return addProduct(product);
    } else {
      return updateProduct(product);
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addProduct(product).then((product) => navigate(`/products/${product.id}`));
  }

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="productName"
          value={product.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="description"
          value={product.description}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="price"
          value={product.price}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3"></Form.Group>
      <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default ProductForm;
```

Comment: I dont See an edit button in the provided code, is it on a "Product" component or in "productList" either way please add that code. Also as a side note, check out react-query as a solution to managing local and server state.

Answer (score 0):

Link to new product should be as route ‘products/new’ unless your redirecting it somewhere

Your handle submit on form always calls addProduct not addOrUpdate